# Does git log list the remote url used for files are commited

Tags: git

Clone a git repo from X git server

Then changed remote url to Y git server

Again changed to X git server

Will X git server has a track list of Y remote server used?

How to get the server list details?

Comment: Please clarify your question, I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: If you clone a repository (X) into a local copy (Y), the original knows nothing about the clone. X will never (using default settings) know the location of Y.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote -v` will give you the remotes your repository connected. You may have more than one remote at the same time. State of the Y will be overridden if you repoint it's remote to X and fetch.